# How to detect arrow function with the Typescript Compiler API

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I try to follow TypeScript wiki example [Using the Type Checker](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#using-the-type-checker) but cannot manage to identify arrow function.

e.g.:

```
/**
 * Hello
 */
export const hello = (): string => 'hello';
```

Is not recognized as an arrow function type by my visitor:

```
function visit(node: ts.Node) {
   console.log(node.kind, ts.isArrowFunction(node)); // -> 236, false
```

on the contrary, standard function are identified:

e.g.

```
/**
 * Hello
 */
export function hello (): string {return 'hello'};
```

is recognized by the visitor with `isFunctionDeclaration`

```
function visit(node: ts.Node) {
   console.log(node.kind, ts.isFunctionDeclaration(node)); // -> 255, true
```

What am I missing? How can I identify arrow function?

Comment: you're probably checking if the variable declaration is an arrow function, not the value it's assigned to? hard to say because we don't know what node you are checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at that code in ts-ast-viewer.com: https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wBbADbYnAXjgAoBKALjnSgEtkBzQgPjgHItcJWBuIA

[image: View of AST from url above]

As can be seen, there is a `VariableStatement` child of the `SourceFile`, then a `VariableDeclarationList`, then a `VariableDeclaration` and finally its initializer is an `ArrowFunction`.

Try going down recursively instead:

```
function findDescendantArrowFunction(node: ts.Node) {
  if (ts.isArrowFunction(node)) {
    return node;
  } else {
    return ts.forEachChild(node, findDescendantArrowFunction);
  }
}

const arrowFunc = findDescendantArrowFunction(sourceFile);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot David! Small typo - `ts.forEachChild(node, findDescendantArrowFunction)` - but solved my issue 