# Create type that only allows normal functions and not arrow functions

Tags: typescript

I'm setting up an object type that allows developers to define a specific property as a function. Behind the scenes, the property is invoked using the `call()` method, where I change `this`. Additionally, I'm allowing developers to access some of the properties of the new `this` (which I set up using the special `this` parameter that tells TypeScript the type of `this` within the function). This of course only works with regular functions because arrow functions cannot change `this` using `call()`, but I can't figure out how to create a type that prevents developers from using arrow functions.
Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the problem:
[image: screenshot]

```
type Effect = {
  irrelevantProp?: any;
  irrelevantProp2?: any;
  // `this` type is changed to MyClass (with limited access)
  specialFunc(this: Pick<MyClass, 'firstName' | 'lastName'>, a: number, b: number): string;
}

class MyClass {
  constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string, private effect: Effect) {}

  doThing() {
    // calls specialFunc() while passing self as `this`
    this.effect.specialFunc.call(this, 5, 7);
  }
}

// good
const effectNormal: Effect = {
  specialFunc(a, b) {
    console.log(this.firstName);
    console.log(this.lastName);
    return 'blabla';
  },
}

// good
const effectNormal2: Effect = {
  specialFunc: function(a, b) {
    console.log(this.firstName);
    console.log(this.lastName);
    return 'hello';
  },
}

// bad
const effectArrow: Effect = {
  specialFunc: (a, b) => { // no error
    console.log(this.firstName); // error
    console.log(this.lastName); // error
    return 'whatever';
  }
  // There's no error on the usage of the arrow function itself, but I WANT an error there
}
```

As you can see, TypeScript already generates an error when `this` is used inside an arrow function since it could possibly be undefined, so the compiler clearly understands the difference between an arrow function and a regular one.

After a lot of Googling, I still don't know how to make a type definition that recognizes that difference that TypeScript clearly knows about. The closest thing I found that was even remotely relevant was this [How to detect arrow function with the Typescript Compiler API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73297955/how-to-detect-arrow-function-with-the-typescript-compiler-api), but I need something that checks at compile time.

Comment: there isn't a way to detect that with the type system. linting and unit tests can help you. or make your api more flexible and pass that state in to the function

Comment: @DanielA.White I see. In my specific case, I don't want to allow the users determine what to pass as `this` themselves (unless I misunderstood what you meant by "pass that state in"), but I might look into the linting solution.

I don't know anything about setting up linters though, so if I may ask first: Would I actually be able to set up a rule that prohibits specific properties from being arrow functions? I understand that linters help enforce formatting rules, but I don't know to what extent. Additionally, would the linting rule be something I can include in the package?

Comment: Unfortunately TS does not strictly enforce `this` types; there's a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#7968](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968) to improve this, but it's not part of the language.  So while you can *express* the typings you care about, TS won't enforce it.  This is essentially the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76530957/2887218).  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, that might be the same problem. In this hypotheticale, I'm trying to enforce that `specialFunc` must not be an arrow function. Technically, TS does give a warning—in the image I included in my post, `this` inside the arrow function gives a TS error: "Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)". That might be good enough since a dev's reaction would probably be to just rewrite it as a normal function. But it would be nice to prevent potentially numerous rewrites (because the dev may define several effects) by just prohibiting `specialFunc` from being an arrow function in the first place.

Comment: My current way of enforcing it is hacky and only checks at run-time: At the very beginning of accepting all of the user's objects, I'm checking their "`specialFunc`"s under the hood in a loop using regex.
`if (generator.toString().match(/^\(.*\) => .*/)) {
      /* bla bla throw new SyntaxError */
}`
This will work fine since, by the nature of what my framework is and how it works, it's extremely likely that a user will only run into this issue once and then understand what not to do. But it would be great to check for arrow functions using TS because I want to maximize user experience.